# I am trying to create an update button that takes an entry from the list box and store in textbox for editing in windowsformsApp

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, listbox, windows-forms-designer

when i select a customer entry the fname, lname and phone will show in the firstname text box i cant seem to separate my textboxfname so fname goes in firstname and so on. i also cant seem to get it to update the information once i have edited it 
this is my code so far:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Customer> CustomerDB = new List<Customer>();

        private string fName, lName, phone;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.lstBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.lstBox_SelectedIndexChanged);


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadDB();
            foreach (Customer Entry in CustomerDB)
            {
                lstBox.Items.Add(Entry.GetCustomer());
            }
        }

        private void LoadDB()
        {

            CustomerDB.Add(new Customer { FName ="Jim", LName = "Smith", Phone = "346-2514" });
            CustomerDB.Add(new Customer { FName = "Jo", LName = "Baker", Phone = "346-1263" });
            CustomerDB.Add(new Customer { FName = "Aimee", LName = "Ellery", Phone = "346-3658" });
            CustomerDB.Add(new Customer { FName = "Sam", LName = "Herewini", Phone = "346-9898" });

        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void btnListCustomers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayCustomers();

        }

        private void btnClearList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//clearlist button
        {
            ClearDisplay();

        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//update button
        {
            int index = lstBox.SelectedIndex;
            if (index == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must first select the entry you wish to update");
                btnAdd.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //txtBoxFName.Text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                //txtBoxLName.Text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                //txtBoxPhone.Text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

            }
            //txtBoxFName.Text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //else if (index != -1)
            //{

            //    lstBox.Items.RemoveAt(index);
            //    lstBox.Items.Insert(index, txtBoxFName.Text);
            //    lstBox.Items.Insert(index, txtBoxLName.Text);
            //    lstBox.Items.Insert(index, txtBoxPhone.Text);

            //}

            //lstBox.Items[0] = lstBox.Items[0];

            //lstBox.SelectedIndex = -1;//deselects a selection

            //txtBoxFName.Text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //txtBoxLName.Text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //txtBoxPhone.Text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //string item = lstBox.GetItemText(lstBox.SelectedItem);

        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//delete button
        {

            if (lstBox.SelectedIndex == -1)//if selected index is choosen then can remove entry
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select the entry you wish to delete.");
            }
            else
            {

                lstBox.Items.RemoveAt(lstBox.SelectedIndex);
            }


        }

        private void lstBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//list box
        {
            int index = lstBox.SelectedIndex;
            if (index != -1)
            {
                txtBoxFName.Text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); ;
                //txtBoxFName.Text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                //txtBoxLName.Text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                //txtBoxPhone.Text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }
            //fName = txtBoxFName.Text;
            //lName = txtBoxLName.Text;
            //phone = txtBoxPhone.Text;
            //txtBoxFName.Text = lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//add button
        {



            if (txtBoxFName.Text == string.Empty)
                {


                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name in the  FirstName text box");
                    txtBoxFName.Focus();
                }
                else if (txtBoxLName.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name in the LastName text box");
                    txtBoxLName.Focus();

                }

                else if (txtBoxPhone.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Phone number in the phone text box");
                    txtBoxPhone.Focus();
                }

                else
                {

                    fName = txtBoxFName.Text;
                    lName = txtBoxLName.Text;
                    phone = txtBoxPhone.Text;

                    lstBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}", fName, lName, phone));

                    txtBoxFName.Clear();
                    txtBoxFName.Focus();



                    txtBoxLName.Clear();
                    txtBoxFName.Focus();



                    txtBoxPhone.Clear();
                    txtBoxFName.Focus();



                }



        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//clears button clears fname,lname and phone text boxes
        {
             ClearBoxes();

        }

        private void ClearBoxes()//method which clears the first name, last name and phone textboxes.
        {
            txtBoxFName.Clear();
            txtBoxFName.Focus();
            txtBoxLName.Clear();
            txtBoxFName.Focus();
            txtBoxPhone.Clear();
            txtBoxFName.Focus();
        }

        private void txtBoxFName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fName = txtBoxFName.Text;
        }

        private void txtBoxLName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lName = txtBoxLName.Text;
        }

        private void txtBoxPhone_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void ClearDisplay()// method which clears the listbox.
        {

            lstBox.Items.Clear();
            txtBoxSearch.Focus();

        }

        private void DisplayCustomers()//method, which adds each customer in the CustomerDB list to the listbox on the form, using the GetCustomer method in the class.
        {
            lstBox.Items.Clear();

            foreach (Customer Entry in CustomerDB)
            {
                lstBox.Items.Add(Entry.GetCustomer());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the task i am struggling with is the Update button and the search button
to use the update button i must be able to do the following:
F
First checking a customer is selected in the listbox If an item is not selected, display a MessageBox saying “Please select a customer to update”, clear the listbox and add customers in the CustomerDB list to the listbox.

The next part of the validation will check the first name, last name and phone textboxes are not empty.  If any of these are empty display the MessageBox saying “All textboxes must be filled to continue.”

If all textboxes are filled; update the CustomerDB attributes with the contents in the first name, last name and phone textboxes, clear the first name, last name and phone textboxes, clear the listbox, and add the updated CustomerDB list back to the listbox on the form.  Lastly display a MessageBox saying “Customer details updated.”  Enable the Add button again here. Selecting an item from the listbox This event should firstly disable the Add button. Then taking the selected item in the listbox, split it into an array of strings, separating each element at the tab space.  Assign each element of this array into the first name, last name and phone textboxes to enable updating.

Then using the first name (the first element in your string array) you can then find the index of that customer in the CustomerDB list, which can be used to update or delete that customer from the list.

Comment: What issue you are facing here?

Comment: when i select a customer entry the fname, lname and phone will show in the firstname text box i cant seem to separate my textboxfname so fname goes in firstname and so on. i also cant seem to get it to update the information once i have edited it